# changing build identifier app getting crash

Tags: ios

i have my home screen with login of `google plus.`. Now my project bundle identifier is `com.appta.product` And my project name is `apptaproduct`. Now my client want to chnage the bundle identifier name to `com.appta.solution`. Now i simple change the target name nad edit the scheme and when i run my app .And when i try to login with `google +` my app getting crash.

Please give some guide to change the build identifier of my project. This is version of 2.1....But before some developer are worked in version 2.1.In that time they used same build identifier`com.appta.product`. So they already have that app in app store.

Now i am newly working in this version.Please help me how can i change the build identifier to work as before.

Please help me thanks!

Comment: what does the crash say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a google+ login, first it always requires to register your application information to https://console.developers.google.com. At google developer console your application still holds your old bundle identifier 'com.appta.product'.

**NOTE:** Solution is to login at google developer console and find your registered application there and change the bundle identifier to new one - 'com.appta.solution'.
Your application google+ login will work thereafter.

Comment: i am new to ios. so what i get is ...i need to change the identifier name in that console....Then i dont need to change the project name or i dont need to chnage the build identifier under in gendral tab in xcode??

Comment: yes exactly just change identifier in that google developer console, identifier should be similar in Xcode and google developer console to get login works fine.